# dijit calendar to display only 52 weeks back from current day in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form, dijit.calendar

I  have a requirement of showing calendar to only 52 weeks back from current day in dojo ,I'm using `dijit/Calendar` for the same,can some one help me by providing light on displaying only 52 weeks back from current day in dijit calendar.

currently I am using `data-dojo-props` which is disabling only weekends in calendar .

```
<div id="mycal" data-dojo-attachpoint="mycal" 
                data-dojo-type="dijit.calendar" 
                data-dojo-props="isDisabledDate:dojo.date.locale.isWeekend">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so simple , you have to do it in programmatic manner ,

Create a calendar dijit , then overide its `isDisabledDate` function by checking both show cal view days are > or are week days : as below

```
return dojoDate.difference(date, new Date(), "day") > disable_before_days || locale.isWeekend(date)  ;
```

See below working snippet :

```js
require(["dojo/parser",
    "dijit/Calendar",
    "dijit/registry",
    "dojo/date",
    "dojo/date/locale",
    "dojo/ready",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(parser, Calendar, registry, dojoDate, locale, ready){

    disable_before_days = 52;

    ready(function(){
      //var calendar = registry.byId("mycal");
      var calendar = new Calendar({
        value: new Date(),
        isDisabledDate:function(date, localString){
          return dojoDate.difference(date, new Date(), "day") > disable_before_days 
              || locale.isWeekend(date) 
              || date > new Date() ;
        }
       }, "mycal");
    });
});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida Grande,Arial !important;
    font-size: 13px !important;
    background: white;
    color: #333;
}

#mycal .dijitCalendarDisabledDate {
    background-color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#mycal .dijitCalendarContainer {
    margin: 25px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojox/calendar/themes/claro/Calendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  dojoConfig = {
    isDebug: true,
    async: true,
    parseOnLoad: true
  }
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<body class="claro">
  <div id="mycal" ></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thankyou verymuch!! ,it worked.Is it possible to disable future dates as well with the existing functionality(ie allow only 52 weeks back by disabling future dates as well).

Comment: @Balaji  juste add `|| date > new Date() ;`  in the return condition , to apply the change at calendar stratup you have to do it in programmatic maner , see aupdated fiddle

Comment: @Balaji mark the answer as resolved if it helpd you :)

Comment: hi Springer ,
Apppricaiate your paticane ,If i do programtically as suggested i am getting below error

"Tried to register widget with id==mycal but that id is already registered".


,I am loading  calendar on click of a button .


however with your previous shared code "var calendar = registry.byId("mycal");" its loading ,but disabling dates are not applying on startup they are applying only after the selection of some date  .

Comment: @Balaji , you have to create div without data-dojo-type ... like  <div id="mycal" ></div>
also , you have to create you calendar no in button click but in the class or starter widget

Comment: am i doing any thing wrong in this <button  data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" data-dojo-attach-event="onClick:oncldriconclick" data-dojo-props="iconClass:' dijitIconTable', showLabel: false" type="button">cldr<span >datepicker</span></button>



<div id="mycal"   data-dojo-attach-event="onclick: _onDayClick"  ></div>

Comment: my requirment is on click of button icon ,calendar should popup ,hence i used above mentined first div fr button icon and second div for getting the values selected by user,

Comment: this is other issue than the question , I need the logic of your button how the code work to understand

Comment: posted my code with new question please check thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563431/loading-dijit-calendar-on-click-of-dijit-icon-button